# How to print the values of Keras tensors?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensor

I have this code and i want to print the keras tensor values of 'out':

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Input

batch_size = 8
inp = Input(shape=(batch_size, 7, 7,2048))
inp = tf.squeeze(inp,axis=0)
print(inp.shape)
layer = Flatten()
out = layer(inp)
print(out.shape)
out = Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(out)
print(out.shape)
print(layer.count_params())
```

i am running Tensorflow 2.6.0 on googele colab, i tried many way to print the out tensor values but nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should feed some data to your model in order to get some output values from your layers.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from keras.layers import Flatten, Dense, Input

### Model setup ###
inp = Input(shape=(7, 7,2048))
# inp = tf.squeeze(inp,axis=0) # ValueError: Graph disconnected
layer = Flatten()
out = layer(inp)
out = Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(out)

model = Model(inputs=inp,outputs=out)

### Data ###
batch_size = 8
my_input = tf.random.uniform(shape=(batch_size,7,7,2048))

print(model(my_input)) # returns a tensor with the shape (batch_size,1)
```